# JavaScript CheckBox Change Color Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, gridview

Hi I am trying to use this checkAll function.

If I click on the checkAll checkbox, then all of the row will be selected and the background color will change accordingly.

Here is my javascript:

```
function checkAll(objRef) {
        var GridView = objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
            var row = inputList[i].parentNode.parentNode;
            if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && objRef != inputList[i]) {
                if (objRef.checked) {
                    row.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
                    inputList[i].checked = true;
                }
                else {
                    if (row.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                        row.style.backgroundColor = "#e4edfb";

                    } else {
                        row.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    }
                    inputList[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hidID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
   <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBoxMultipleSelect" CssClass="chkBoxMultipleSelect" OnClick="checkIfUnselected(this);" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

After click on the checkAll checkBox, I am only able to change the color of that checkbox column only, but not my other column.

Any help is apparated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function checkAll(spanChk) {
        var IsChecked = spanChk.checked;
        var Chk = spanChk;
        Parent = document.getElementById('gvMessageReportShow');
        var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].id != Chk && items[i].type == "checkbox") {
                if (items[i].checked != IsChecked) {
                    spanChk.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua';
                    items[i].click();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I ended up finding my answer here

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/132_GridView_with_CheckBox_%E2%80%93_Select_All_and_Highlight_Selected_Row.aspx